# Dual NICs with different gateways

Tags: route

So I'm setting up a phone system (FreePBX, CentOS based), with one NIC setup for the internal network and a second NIC setup for a separate LAN, that is from our SIP Trunk provider:

`192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.25
192.168.150.0/30 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.150.2`

I've been able to set `eth0` as the default gateway, but need to make sure traffic for the 192.168.150.0/30 network goes out `eth1`, here's our current routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.150.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I've tried adding a static route for the 192.168.150.0/30 (gateway 192.168.150.1), but this fails. Am I missing something obvious?

- In response to @111, I've tried that, but the system tells me the file already exists, and then I tried deleting that route and re-adding manually, but then it informs me that the network is unreachable without adding the route. Here's the output of `ip route` for more details if that helps (this is after resetting all configuration and restarting the network service).

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1003
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.25
192.168.150.0/30 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.150.2
```

Comment: Your current setup will send all traffic out `eth0` (your default gateway) with the exception of traffic with the destination `192.168.150.0/30`, which should go out `eth1`. Do you want two default gateways?

Comment: @111 I do hope that was a rhetorical question. You can't (by definition) have two default gateways.

Comment: I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to any kind of complex networking, so basically yes? What I want is routing table's last line to look like this: ``192.168.150.0    192.168.150.1    255.255.255.252``, am I just not understanding how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.150.0/30 via 192.168.150.1 dev eth1
```

This should specify the host at 192.168.150.1 as your first hop to other hosts on that `192.168.150.0/30` network. All other traffic will still be routed out of eth0.